Find a set A that satisfies the following
Find a set A with a order relation such that:
$$\forall a, b,c \in A, \inf({\sup({a,c}),b}) = \sup({\inf({a,b}),\inf({a,c})})$$
It's easy to find a set A of two or one element that satisfies this, but i'm in problem to find a set A with at least 3 elements satisfying this property (considering a ordered set A, i.e., all elements of A are real numbers, for example).

You're sure it's not meant to be $\inf({\sup({b,c}),a}) = \sup({\inf({a,b}),\inf({a,c})})$,  which should remind you of $(B\cap C)\cup A = (B\cap A)\cup (C\cap A)$?

no, it's in fact what I had written

Are you sure you can find it with 2 elements? Notice that with 2 elements, either those infs and sups don't always exist or those elements are related, for example, $A={0,1}$ with $0<1$. In this example, with $a=0$ and $b=c=1$, we obtain $1=0$, a contradiction.

Indeed, if those infs and sups always exist (in which case, the ordered set is called a lattice), then the only examples you can find are the singletons. I suspect it must be as JMoravitz asked, in which case any distributive lattice will do.

You are right, I didn't find with 2 elements too. But the question is supposed to be correct.

I think that those infs and sups exist for all elements for A, but the question didn't limit this.

No, you can't find it with more than one element, unless either some of the infs or sups don't exist

But if they don't exist, you can't calculate them

Ok, I am according with you
